# Couchbase index sizing

Tags: couchbase

I have one cluster with one node.

**Community** Edition 5.1.1 build 5723.
I am trying to figure out disk requirements.

I have around **320 million** docs, **250 giga** of data (after compaction)
and 4 **GSI** indexes.

Document key is 60 characters long and index key is 42 characters long and a number (long).

**CREATE INDEX index_tx_from ON tx-history(from,blockNumber) WITH { “defer_build”:true }**

When I used a single **2 Tera SSD**, I ran out of disk space.

I delete the indexes, run only one of them (as in the above example), the size reach **800 gig**, but after compaction, its on **100 gig** only.

This specific index will hold all the docs, the rest of the indexes will be smaller.

As I see it I need 1 tera ssd for data, 2 tera? or even more (seperate disk) for indexing, but this is only cause of compaction requirements.

My questions are:

1. How can I calculate the most accurate disk size.
2. What is the best approach to reduce the size,

   - doc key can't be shorter

Thanks,
Ady.

Comment: How many documents in the tx-history bucket?

Comment: 320 millions and growing

Comment: Couchbase 5.5+ supports compression.https://blog.couchbase.com/store-less-using-data-compression/ geuss that would help to save storage in some way.

Comment: 5.5 is enterprise edition, I am with community.

Comment: FWIW, the Community Edition is using an older storage engine for GSI indexes which is less-than-optimal for these large scale use cases.  Without seeing the logs and stats, I'd assume that you are more running into a write amplification issue rather than steady-state sizing (though one could argue there isn't a difference...disk space is needed either way).

Are you building a new index from scratch on top of the 320M items?  It might be good to see if there is a difference when creating the index first and gradually adding items.  That will give you a better idea of steady-state sizing.

Comment: Couchbase has developed a new storage engine for the Enterprise Edition that is both faster and more efficient.  I totally understand that you're using the Community Edition now, but we'd be happy to help you test out the difference and see if the benefits in the Enterprise Edition are worth it to you.

The Enterprise Edition also now supports index partitioning which will let you spread an index over multiple nodes rather than constrain it to a single one.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the general sizing guidelines for Couchbase:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/install/sizing-general.html

Couchbase stores documents in a compressed format using the Snappy library.  It's done that for quite some time (since version 3.x, if I'm not mistaken).  The new feature in CB 5.5 Enterprise Edition deals with compressing documents in RAM; it's a per-bucket setting.

There are a few performance issues with your particular setup:

- Running a large dataset on a single node with a mix of key/value operations and N1QL queries.  At the very least, you should consider multiple nodes with ample RAM, CPU, and disk space.
- You should consider optimizing your indexes.  The index definition in your post will effectively have 320M+ records.  Here is an article that can help you get started (check out the partial indexes section): https://blog.couchbase.com/database-indexing-best-practices/ .

There is also a plethora of N1QL information in Couchbase N1QL guides (available for download in PDF): https://blog.couchbase.com/a-guide-to-n1ql-features-in-couchbase-5-5-special-edition/